# Swift array filter closure as argument

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, closures

i have an generic class, which store some data of the generic type in an array.

**Class**

```
class TestClass<T> {
    var data: [T]

    // Constructor and some methods.... 
}
```

Now i want to implement the option to get an already filtered array, by posting the filter closure as argument. I tried:

**Filter method**

```
class TestClass<T> {

    typealias FilterBlock = (item: T) -> Bool

    func getData(filter: FilterBlock) {
        data.filter(filter)
    }

}
```

But this raises the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(item: T) -> Bool' to expected argument type '_ -> Bool'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? I copied and pasted exactly what you have here and called the getData method with a FilterBlock but didn't get any error.

Comment: I added the method as a static method

Comment: Even as a non static method i get this error

Comment: What version of Swift and Xcode are you using?  I can't reproduce this error in Xcode 7.1.